# Dugundji: There are continuous nowhere differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation

In Topology by James Dugunji, it is trying to be proven that there are functions with no derivatives at any point and that the set of such functions form a second category set in $C(I)$ (where $I=[0,1]$).

The proof starts by trying to prove that
$$N_n=\left\{f\in C(I)\left|\; \exists x\in\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right],\forall h\in\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right],\;\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|\leq n\right\}\right.$$
is closed for all $n$. This is done by using the continuity of $\omega\colon C(I)\times I\to \mathbb{R}$, the evaluation map, to conclude that
$$\left\{(f,x)\in C(I)\times [0,1-1/n]\left|\; \left|\frac{f(x+h_0)-f(x)}{h_0}\right|\leq n\right\}\right.$$
is closed for every $h_0\in(0,1/n]$ and then using the projection parallel to the compact $[0,1-1/n]$ to conclude that
$$N(h_0)=\left\{f\in C(I)\left|\; \exists x\in\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right],\;\left|\frac{f(x+h_0)-f(x)}{h_0}\right|\leq n\right\}\right.$$
is closed for every $h_0\in(0,1/n]$. So far so good. My problem is in what follows: Dugundji claims that $N_n=\bigcap\{N(h_0)\mid h_0\in(0,1/n]\}$; I don't agree with this statement. If $f$ belong to the RHS, then $\forall h\in (0,1/n],\,f\in N(h_0)$, that is $\forall h\in(0,1/n],\exists x\in [0,1-1/n],\; \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|\leq n$ which is a weaker property than that held by the elements on $N_n$.

Is there something that I'm missing? Is the equality actually correct?

Source: Topology James Dugundji, Chap. XIV, proposition 4.2.

Comment: You say second category in $C(I)$, what topology does $C(I)$ have?

Comment: I believe this is a genuine mistake. The proof I once saw instead used the existence - from an explicit construction - of a nowhere differentiable function to conclude that the somewhere-differentiable functions are of first category.

Comment: @Jakobian the topology of $C(I)$ is the compact-open topology. Since $I$ is compact, the compact-open topology and the uniform topology are the same: $C(I)$ can be equiped with the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in I} |f(x)-g(x)|$.

Comment: @FShrike that'd be a bummer. The only reason Dugundji added this proposition was to show how the Baire theorem can be used to prove existence in Analysis

Comment: You don't need any sort of clever argument to conclude that $N_n$ is closed though. If $f_m\in N_n$, $f_m\to f$ and $x_m\in [0, 1-1/n]$ are such that this whole thing holds, you can assume $x_m$ converges by taking a subsequence. Then take limit of $\left | \frac{f_m(x_m+h)-f_m(x_m)}{h}\right|$

Comment: There are a lot- It has been proved that for all continuous function $f$ there exists one of these weird functions   so near of $f$ as we want to have. In other words there are infinitely many of these functions that Poincaré qualifies of "monster".in his time.